# Flask Session variable gets deleted after each request

Tags: python, session, flask

I have a messenger chat bot which asks questions. To keep track of the questions I have set a session variable called `counter`. The bot moves on to the next question when the `counter` is incremented.

I initialized the counter to 0 in the beginning. But every time the bot responds by sending a request the session variable gets deleted and gets re-initialized to 0.

Here's my checking code

```
def recieve_incoming_messages():

    if "counter" not in session:
        session['counter'] = 0
        session.permanent = True
        print("session is initialized to 0 here")
    else:
        print("session still exists")
        session['counter'] +=0
```

This if condition checks if 'counter' is in the session object, if it doesn't exit, it creates it. But, the first condition becomes true all the time and reinitializes to 0(should only happen if counter doesn't exist). 
As I know Flask session variables should exist unless explicitly cleared or when the session is expired.

Why does the counter variable gets deleted? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Have you checked on the client-side whether the session, as well as all session variables, are actually being stored in the first place?

Comment: @yoonjesung I'm not sure how that's supposed to work. Messenger app doesn't store sessions I guess.

Comment: If it is a web-app, you can inspect the application cookie/local-storage data and see if the client is actually storing the session data. No session data = no session['counter']. Or in your method check the contents of the session or if session is None

Comment: @yoonjesung Thanks! I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980855/storing-session-variables-in-facebook-messenger. It is a web-app. How do I inspect the application cookie/local-storage data?

Comment: If using Chrome, right-click => Inspect => Application => Cookies/Session Storage/Local Storage => check if session exists

Comment: Are you sure it is deleted? After the initialization of the counter, its value never changes as you have `session['counter'] +=0` in the else part. Ignoring problems regarding the client-side, I suggest correcting that part. I guess it should be `session['counter'] += 1`

Comment: The counter +=1 part is in a different function. And the +=0 part is just to ignore some errors and debug. The problem is messenger doesn't store session cookies on the client side, every thing gets reset, that's why it throws an error and creates and initializes counter to 0. @ohannes

Comment: Have you set the `app.secret_key` to some key of yours? If not then flask session may not work.

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
session.modified = True
```

whenever you modify sessions you need to save it. Refer:[flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.session.modified)